# Xcode - copy files when running an app on the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

For some reason Xcode has stopped copying files to an app when I try running it.

In the past, I've dragged in a file, kept the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" option ticked, and all has been well.

Recently, however, I've had to go into the Targets / Build Phases / Copy Bundle Resources and manually add each file for it to be added to the app.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same view where you check "Copy items to destination group's folder" you have to check the targets you want to have access to the files!

Comment: Now that's annoying. I guess I'd just got into the habit of only checking the top option! Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If something like this happens, perform the following.

1. Close the project, **not Xcode**.
2. Open Organizer. Go to *Projects* ->
   Delete the derived data for the required project.
3. Quit Xcode.
4. Go to the `Project` folder in the Finder. Open the package of your ---.xcodeproj
   file. Other than the project settings file, delete all the files.
5. Now open Xcode and your project. First it will do some indexing of your
   project. Then build and run.

Now it will add all the files.

Comment: Thanks - very detailed instructions. Just tried it but it's still not automatically copying in the Bundle Resources.